# Get the error "Person(instance) does not recognize setName" when code executed

Tags: objective-c

When I write my first Objective-C demo,

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Person : NSObject
@property (assign) NSString *name;
- (void)display;
@end

@implementation Person
- (void)display{
    NSLog(@"Name is %@", self.name);
}
@end

int main() {
    Person *p = [[Person alloc] init];
    p.name = @"Kyle";
    [p display];
    return 0;
}
```

I always get the exception:

> Uncaught exception NSInvalidArgumentException, reason: Person(instance) does not recognize setName:

Besides, I always get some strange warnings, such as `incomplete implementation of class ‘Person’`.

Here is the detailed output：

```
/usercode/file.m:13:1: warning: incomplete implementation of class ‘Person’ [enabled by default]
 @end
 ^
/usercode/file.m:13:1: warning: method definition for ‘-setName:’ not found [enabled by default]
/usercode/file.m:13:1: warning: method definition for ‘-name’ not found [enabled by default]
2021-03-18 07:28:46.540 a.out[11] autorelease called without pool for object (0x84a2f8) of class NSMethodSignature in thread <NSThread: 0x7ee668>
2021-03-18 07:28:46.556 a.out[11] autorelease called without pool for object (0x8d5168) of class NSMutableDataMalloc in thread <NSThread: 0x7ee668>
2021-03-18 07:28:46.556 a.out[11] autorelease called without pool for object (0x84b3e8) of class GSCodeBuffer in thread <NSThread: 0x7ee668>
2021-03-18 07:28:46.556 a.out[11] autorelease called without pool for object (0x8d5288) of class NSMethodSignature in thread <NSThread: 0x7ee668>
2021-03-18 07:28:46.556 a.out[11] autorelease called without pool for object (0x8d08f8) of class GSFFIInvocation in thread <NSThread: 0x7ee668>
2021-03-18 07:28:46.556 a.out[11] autorelease called without pool for object (0x8d0278) of class GSCInlineString in thread <NSThread: 0x7ee668>
2021-03-18 07:28:46.556 a.out[11] autorelease called without pool for object (0x8d5138) of class NSException in thread <NSThread: 0x7ee668>
2021-03-18 07:28:46.563 a.out[11] autorelease called without pool for object (0x8c62f8) of class NSLongLongNumber in thread <NSThread: 0x7ee668>
2021-03-18 07:28:46.563 a.out[11] autorelease called without pool for object (0x8c6d68) of class NSLongLongNumber in thread <NSThread: 0x7ee668>
2021-03-18 07:28:46.563 a.out[11] autorelease called without pool for object (0x8d24e8) of class NSLongLongNumber in thread <NSThread: 0x7ee668>
2021-03-18 07:28:46.563 a.out[11] autorelease called without pool for object (0x8c4e38) of class NSLongLongNumber in thread <NSThread: 0x7ee668>
2021-03-18 07:28:46.563 a.out[11] autorelease called without pool for object (0x8d2e28) of class NSLongLongNumber in thread <NSThread: 0x7ee668>
2021-03-18 07:28:46.563 a.out[11] autorelease called without pool for object (0x8d2648) of class NSLongLongNumber in thread <NSThread: 0x7ee668>
2021-03-18 07:28:46.563 a.out[11] autorelease called without pool for object (0x8d0718) of class NSLongLongNumber in thread <NSThread: 0x7ee668>
2021-03-18 07:28:46.563 a.out[11] autorelease called without pool for object (0x7ccff8) of class NSIntNumber in thread <NSThread: 0x7ee668>
2021-03-18 07:28:46.563 a.out[11] autorelease called without pool for object (0x874808) of class NSLongLongNumber in thread <NSThread: 0x7ee668>
2021-03-18 07:28:46.563 a.out[11] autorelease called without pool for object (0x7fcc18) of class NSIntNumber in thread <NSThread: 0x7ee668>
/usercode/a.out: Uncaught exception NSInvalidArgumentException, reason: Person(instance) does not recognize setName:
```

Anyone could help me handle the issue? TIA.

Comment: I would take the autorelease pool warning seriously if I were you.

Comment: @matt But according to my limited knowledge, this is not the cause of the exception.

Comment: In `@property (assign)`, `assign` shouldn't be used for `NSString` but only for primitive (int, bool, float, etc.). Change it to "basic" `nontatomic, strong` (that could be changed to "nonatomic, copy" later should make it work.

Comment: Which IDE or compiler do you use?

Comment: @Larme Thanks for your advise. But when changed to `nonatomic, strong`, it gives me error `error: unknown property attribute before ‘)’ token
 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;`.

Comment: `nonatomic, retain` then? What version are your using? For macOS? Recent OS? No ARC?

Comment: @Willeke I test the code on 3 online compilers. And all of them give me the same warning or error.

Comment: @Larme I just test the demo on online compilers. Will this raise an exception?

Comment: So you're not using Xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using "online compilers" which know nothing of Objective-C 2.0 features such as self-synthesizing properties, on which your code depends. It would be a lot simpler to use Xcode if your aim is to learn the Objective-C that Xcode uses. Let's turn this into a command-line tool in Xcode; this file is now *main.m*...

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Person : NSObject
@property (assign) NSString *name;
- (void)display;
@end

@implementation Person
- (void)display{
    NSLog(@"Name is %@", self.name);
}
@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        Person *p = [[Person alloc] init];
        p.name = @"Kyle";
        [p display];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

That compiles and runs as expected.

Comment: Thx. You are right. It works fine in Xcode!